# Why does SwiftUI react to willSet in Published

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I was wondering why is that `Published` property wrapper fires in `willSet` and not in `didSet`. For the UI this probably doesn't make a difference, but for a lot of other places a property wrapper that reacts to `didSet` would make more sense because we can read new value when reacting to the change. I used to work with a custom `property wrapper` that wraps `CurrentValueSubject`, and then I have this kind of behavior. Just wondering why it is designed this way. Does it have some puropse?

Comment: I don't understand the question - you *can* use `didSet` in `@Published` property wrappers and use the new value.

Comment: When I use sink on published property to consume the event, then it is called before new value is assigned, so it uses willSet. I'm not talking about using didSet myself. Im just wondering why new combine send() event is called in this property wrapper in willSet and not in didSet.

Comment: See if this thread helps you: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-this-a-bug-in-published/31292/28